# AngularJS: how do I get the hash value within the URL

Tags: angularjs, url, hash

AngularJS noob here.

I want my application to be able to respond to a url hash. By respond I mean simple stuff like set a variable value.

In this example, if the url is ***http:example.com/#parents-to-be***, I want the app to perform the standard behaviour which is scroll to ***#parents-to-be***, and also set ***$scope.tab3 = 1;***

From doing some research, it seems like this can be achieved with a combination of ***$location.hash()*** and ***$anchorScroll()***. However, I haven't been successful thus far. Can someone please help?

html:

```
<div ng-app="bug">
    <div ng-controller="TabsController">
        <a href ng-click="activateTab(1)">tab 1</a>
        <a href ng-click="activateTab(2)">tab 2</a>
        <a href ng-click="activateTab(3)">tab 3</a>

        <div id="parents-to-be"> <!-- this is the target div -->
            <div ng-show="tab1 === 1">content of tab 1</div>
            <div ng-show="tab2 === 1">content of tab 2</div>
            <div ng-show="tab3 === 1">content of tab 3</div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /angular tabs controller scope -->    
</div> <!-- /angular app scope -->
```

app.js:

```
(function() {
        var app = angular.module('bug', []);
        app.controller('TabsController', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
            // init tabs
            $scope.initTabs = function() {
                $scope.tab1 = 0;
                $scope.tab2 = 0;
                $scope.tab3 = 0;
            };
            // activate tabs
            $scope.activateTab = function(tab_index) {
                $scope.initTabs();
                $scope['tab' + tab_index] = 1;
            };
            // this is the part of the app where I try to get the hash value and edit the value of tab3
            $scope.hash_value = $location.hash();
            if ($scope.hash_value === "parents-to-be") {
                $scope.activateTab(3);
                $anchorScroll();
            }
        });
    })();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `$location.search()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$on` event handler to capture the hash value after the `$locationChangeSuccess` event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function()
 {
 console.log(arguments[1].replace(/[^#]+(#.+)/, "$1") );
 }
)

angular.element(document).injector().get('$rootScope').$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(){console.log(arguments[1].replace(/[^#]+(#.+)/, "$1"))})
```

**References**

- [feat($location): add support for History API state handling](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6fd36deed954b338e48390862971d465148dc1f2)
- [hashchange Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange)